# Linking to acts_as_taggable_on tags within a Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I've got a very simple setup of posts with associated tags.  When I 'show' a post I want to be able to link to each one of those tags BUT it seems to only link to the tag :id that shares the :id of the post I'm showing.

My code:

```
<% @post.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag, tag_path() %>
<% end %>
```

Let's say I'm looking at post number 2, the above will only link me to /tags/2 , no matter which tag I click on.  I'm sure the answer is embarrassingly simple but it's driving me crazy. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `tag` to your route helper:

```
<% @post.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

Change `tag_list` to `tags`:

```
<% @post.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that Jordan but it just links to the tag name, not the id which means it doesn't work.  ie, it'll link me to tags/tag rather than tags/1